# Simular Angular Binding com JavaScript Puro

Tags: javascript, html

É possível simular o data binding do Angular em javascript puro?

Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
 
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Código retirado de [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default)

Comment: Olá @gabriel bem vindo ao StackOverflow, você precisa demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar esses links. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve). Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Somento com JS puro seria algo como:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

            <div>
                <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
                <p>Name : <input type="text" id="inputNome" placeholder="Enter name here" onChange="mudouInput()"></p>
                <h1 id="nome">Hello </h1>

            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
             function mudouInput() {
              inputValue = document.getElementById('inputNome').value;
              document.getElementById('nome').innerHTML = "Hello " + inputValue;
             }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sugiro trocar on `onChage` por `onKeyUp` para o efeito ficar igual ao do exemplo